# ActiveMerchant Integration usage example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

Where can I find a complete example of `ActiveMerchant` Integrations usage? I can see tons of examples of Gateways' usage, but couldn't see how an Integration should be used (e.g. what do you do in the `return_url` and `cancel_return_url` controller actions?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there are any concrete example of ActiveMerchant Integrations usage (maybe this will help: http://peepcode.com/products/activemerchant-pdf), but I can tell you that it depends on the payment gateway.

I would suggest to make a test transaction and see what params are returned to you by the gateway and then make a code that uses those params.

For example, in case of 2checkout you would want to check md5 hash that 2checkout returns to verify the transaction and make a record of the payment (maybe save the raw params received from 2checkout). Of course, it also depends what type of notification method your payment gateway provides.

Comment: I know how to perform the communication with the payment provider; what I don't know is how an Integration (my Integration) should be used in a standard way...

Comment: It all depends on payment gateway. If you look at the docs (http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/) you'll see that each integration has ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::Return (http://activemerchant.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveMerchant/Billing/Integrations/Return.html) implemented, more or less, and it includes methods such as success?() and message().

Comment: The linked PDF is very unhelpful (you have to buy it, and I can't judge if it contains "integration" usage)

Answer (score 4):

I created an example [Active Merchant integration with 2Checkout tutorial](https://github.com/craigchristenson/2checkout_rails_example) if you are still interested.